# Scrolling the iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am a beginner in iphone development, and I want to make scrolling in the iphone simulator.

How can I make it possible? Can anybody give me code for it?

Comment: You might take time to further explain your question, I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `ScrollViewSuite` example that Apple gives then.  They use scroll views in a couple different ways to show off what they can do.

More information here:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html